# Evaluate mathematical strings in python 3.7

Tags: python, math, expression, formula, python-3.7

I am looking for a function specifically for python 3.7. I have a mathematical expression in a string :

```
str="2^10"   #Expected output: 1024
```

Is there any in-built function in python 3.7 to evaluate it?

P.S: eval() function doesnt work.

Comment: I am pretty sure it works https://repl.it/repls/WideeyedDutifulRecursion. However you might be looking for `str="2**10"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The symbol for power operations in Python is `**`, not `^`. So, change your string first.

```
str_ ="2^10"

print(eval(str_.replace('^', '**')))  # -> 1024
```

**Note that `eval` is a potentially very dangerous function. Do not use it blindly.**

---

A safer way would be with the (non-standard) module `numexpr`.

```
import numexpr

print(numexpr.evaluate(str_.replace('^', '**')))  # -> 1024
```

Also note that not replacing `"^"` with `"**"` would result in `8`. That happens because in Python `^` is the [*binary XOR*](http://www.xcprod.com/titan/XCSB-DOC/binary_xor.html)